# Inheritance & Json in Golang

Tags: json, go

There are two structures A & B. B includes A. Also there is a function attached to A. It returns json of the parent object. I expect to see all object fields in json when I call the fonction on instance of B, but I get only fields of A. Please look at the code:

```
type A struct {
    Foo string
}

type B struct {
    A
    Bar string
}

func (object *A) toJson() []byte {
    res, _ := json.Marshal(&object)
    return res
}


func main() {
    b := B{}
    fmt.Println(string(b.toJson()))
}
```

I expect to get **{"Foo":"", "Bar":""}** but the result is **{"Foo":""}**. The first way is to define two separate functions for both of structures. But is there the second solution with one function? Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Your methodn toJson() is from A struct. change it to struct B then  you will get your expected result.

```
package main

import (
    "encoding/json"
    "fmt"
)

type A struct {
    Foo string `json:"foo"`
}

type B struct {
    A
    Bar string `json:"bar"`
}

func (object *B) toJson() []byte {
    res, _ := json.Marshal(&object)
    return res
}

func main() {
    c := B{}
    fmt.Println(string(c.toJson()))
}
```

Comment: This is the first way I've described in the question. In this case I need to define two separate functions to be used for A and for B. But does any option exist in Go to define a single function that will work for both structures like method in classic OOP?

Comment: I don't think you could do that in Go,  because here Go doesn't have inheritance but embedding. you can see the docs about embedding here  https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding. just like Andy Answer

Comment: https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=7YcLIbG1ekM&feature=youtu.be and this video explain all about the concept how to write Go. hope it helps

Answer (score 2):

Since `toJson` is defined for `A`, it operates on `b.A`. Embedding a type in Go is not the same as subclassing in other languages. See https://golang.org/doc/effective_go.html#embedding.